# HTML/CSS: unordered list in nav element slightly offset right

Tags: html, css, alignment, padding, nav

I recently made a nav bar with centered content, containing an unordered list of `inline` list items (two or three buttons).

```css
nav,header {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5rem auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style-position: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.7rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="btn" id="one" href="#">button 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="btn" id="two" href="#">button 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[Nav bar slight misalignment to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Kkd.png)

The content was roughly centered, but slightly offset to the right. (It's easy to miss, but pops out when the list and the element above it are similar length). I suspected this was due to 'ghost bullets,' because of the positioning, but I tried setting `list-style-position` to `outside` or `none` and manipulating various margin, padding and align features with no luck. (Note: the solution is zero-padding in the `ul`, see below).

Answer (score 3):

The `ul` element has default padding, which can be overridden easily in the CSS:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Zero-padding fixes nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRVre.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the html of your example using your browsers debug tools, you will see that `ul` has default left padding shown here in green:

[image]

Remove the default padding from the `ul` with `padding: 0;`.

```css
nav,header {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5rem auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style-position: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.7rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="btn" id="one" href="#">button 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="btn" id="two" href="#">button 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```